# Calculate sum of elements in an array within a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, sum

I'm doing a prework for a course I'm going to attend and I have to complete some ex.   I started learning JS last week so I'm a newbie and in this ex I don't have to use any method that allows me to calculate the sum. I only have to use logic. (for loops-functions-switch)

This is the ex: Define a function that will receive an array as an argument and calculate a sum of all its elements. For example, if we pass the following array to that function: const prices = [5, 7.99, 9.99, 0.99, 21], it should return 44.97 as output. How would you concatenate $ sign in front of the sum?

I don't really know how to do that sum, in fact the code I've written is totally wrong but I'd like to understand the logic behind.

```
function calculator (someArray) {
  let result;
  for(let i=0; i<= someArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(someArray[i]);
  }
  result=someArray[i] + someArray[i+=1];
}

const prices = [5, 7.99, 9.99, 0.99, 21];

calculator(prices);
```

I've now changed the code but it only prints the first 2 elements of the array:

```
function calculator (someArray) {
  let result;
  for(let i = 0; i<= someArray.length; i++) {
    result = someArray[i] + (someArray[i+=1]);
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }
}

const prices = [5, 7.99, 9.99, 0.99, 21];

calculator(prices);
```

Comment: Your code is not working, there is a mismatched parenthesis and you didn't return the `result` in `calculator` function.

Comment: Great start. Not only you have coded something but you asked the question very well. Regarding the code itself: you have an offset-by-one error (actually 2) , which is not executed because of your premature `return`. But this is normal, just keep going (y)

Comment: you are going outside of the array twice: once with "<=" and the second time(s) with "i+1" - I think...
The for loop increments i, so there is no need to increment inside of it.
See my answer for a few ways of doing sum...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is the ex: Define a function that will receive an array as an
> argument and calculate a sum of all its elements. For example, if we
> pass the following array to that function: const prices = [5, 7.99,
> 9.99, 0.99, 21], it should return 44.97 as output. How would you concatenate $ sign in front of the sum?

Javascript has a nice feature: reduce

```js
function calculator (someArray){
  return someArray.reduce((howMuchSoFar,currentElementOfTheArray) => {
    howMuchSoFar = howMuchSoFar + currentElementOfTheArray;
    return howMuchSoFar;
  });
}

const prices = [5, 7.99, 9.99, 0.99, 21];

console.log("$"+calculator(prices));
```

(intentionally verbose)

Going back to your original code (a classic for loop)

- arrays go from 0 to length-1, control that
- whathever[i+=1] is actually doing two things: i=i+1 and bringing whatever[i] , it is better going step by step for now, and inside the loop you're already doing i++ so this won't be good
- return is for the whole function, not for each step of a classic for. If needed, go with break, but please understand firstly the while loop

```js
function calculator (someArray){
  let result=0;
  for( let i = 0; i< someArray.length; i++){  
    result = result + someArray[i];
  }
  return result;
}

const prices = [5, 7.99, 9.99, 0.99, 21];

console.log("$"+calculator(prices));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function calculator1(someArray) {
  let result=0;
  for(let i=0; i<someArray.length; i++) {
    result=result+someArray[i];
  }
  return result;
}

function calculator2(someArray) {
  let result=0;
  for(let i=0; i<someArray.length; i++) {
    result+=someArray[i];
  }
  return result;
}

function calculator3(someArray) {
  return someArray.reduce((accumulator, currentValue)=>accumulator+currentValue,0);
}

const prices=[5, 7.99, 9.99, 0.99, 21];

console.log("calculator1: "+calculator1(prices));
console.log("calculator2: "+calculator2(prices));
console.log("calculator3: "+calculator3(prices));

let sumWithDollarSign="$"+calculator3(prices);
console.log("sumWithDollarSign: "+sumWithDollarSign);
```

`calculator1` is straight-forward JavaScript.
`calculator2` uses `+=` which means: add the right side to the left.
`calculator3` uses `Array.reduce` with `accumulator` starting with value `0`, iterating over all items in Array - each is in `currentValue`, and adding to `accumulator` and returning it at the end.

`"$"+someNumber` concatenates the two.  Enough that one of the 2 (or more) is a String to return a String.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error

replace this

```
     result = someArray[i] + (someArray[i+=1];
```

with

```
     result = someArray[i] + (someArray[i+=1]);
```